# Running QGIS viewshed plugin from console?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I want to run the [viewshed plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ViewshedAnalysis/) from the console/ in a script in QGIS.

Do you know if this is possible?